# Android - Is there a better way to toggle a radio button on page load?

Tags: android, radio-button

My current code fetches a database cursor when the page loads and then pre-fills the form. I am trying to check the proper radio button based whether user gender is "Male" or "Female". My 2 radio buttons is in a RadioGroup;

Java code:

```
public void fillData(Cursor row) {
    sId = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.studentid);
    fName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstName);
    lName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lastName);
    gender = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.male);
    gender2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.female);
    course = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.course);
    age = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.age);
    address = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.address);

    sId.setText(row.getString(0));
    fName.setText(row.getString(1));
    lName.setText(row.getString(2));
    String temp = row.getString(3);
    if (temp == "Male") {
        gender.toggle();
    } else {
        gender2.toggle();
    }
    course.setText(row.getString(4));
    age.setText(row.getString(5));
    address.setText(row.getString(6));

}
```

With this code I am only getting the female radio button checked even if temp is "Male". I tested using Toast.maketext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compare string with equals method

```
if ("Male".equals(temp) {
        gender.toggle();
    } else {
        gender2.toggle();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **equalsIgnoreCase()** in case of string matching this will be a good approach.

```
if ("Male".equalsIgnoreCase(temp) {
        gender.toggle();
    } else {
        gender2.toggle();
    }
```